# Shader problem in MonoGame on Android with gl_FragDepth

Tags: android, opengl-es, monogame

I'm using MonoGame and I've got a shader that I'm using to merge a color texture and depth texture with my MonoGame rendered data. It's working fine in my UWP (Universal Windows) build, but it is failing in my Android build.

The MonoGame pipeline compiles my HLSL just fine, but it fails at runtime when GL.CompileShader call in Shader.OpenGL.cs with this error:

> ERROR: 0:18: 'gl_FragDepth' : undeclared identifier`

The compiled shader looks like this:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

vec4 ps_r0;
uniform sampler2D ps_s0;
uniform sampler2D ps_s2;
varying vec4 vTexCoord0;
#define ps_v0 vTexCoord0
#define ps_oC0 gl_FragColor
#define ps_oDepth gl_FragDepth

void main()
{
    ps_oC0 = texture2D(ps_s0, ps_v0.xy);
    ps_r0 = texture2D(ps_s2, ps_v0.xy);
    ps_oDepth = ps_r0.x;
}
```

I've tried on a couple of devices, both of which are using OpenGL ES 3.2 as verified by this output:

`V/AndroidGameView(20506): Created GLES 3.2 Context`

As far as I can tell, `gl_FragDepth` should be supported. And this is happening during the fragment shader as I get no error about using the `gl_FragColor` command.

If I don't modify the depth and just set the color (so the shader does include `gl_FragColor`) then it compiles and works just fine.

So it seems to specifically be the depth.

Everything I read says this should work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mentioned `gl_FragDepth` somewhere in your vertex shader? Error 0:18 means it happened on line 18 of the vertex shader. If it were the fragment shader, it would say Error 1:18 (or whatever line you have the error on). Errors are logged with `shader index:line number`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The fragment shader can be attached first to the program object, the order doesn't matter. Line 18 is that one where `gl_FragDepth` is used. Further is mention in the question *"If I don't modify the depth and just set the color [...] then it compiles and works just fine."*

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not specifying a vertex shader, so it's just using the default one MonoGame provides which has no mention of `gl_FragDepth`. And right before I see the error during `GL.CompileShader` is a call to `GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader)`. So it sure seems like it should work.

Comment: So it seems that MonoGame uses MojoShader to convert the HLSL shaders and MojoShader only generates version 100 shaders. And for this to work, I need version 300 shaders. So that's a pickle.